# .Net HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<Result<TResponse>> getting null always in the TResponse value

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, dotnet-httpclient, httpresponsemessage

When I do the request using Postman I get:

[image]

This is what I am expecting:

```
public class Result<TResultType>
{
    public int? ErrorId { get; protected set; } // Todo: Use it!!!
    public bool Success { get; protected set; }
    public ResponseErrorType ErrorType { get; protected set; }
    public string Message { get; protected set; }
    public TResultType Data { get; protected set; }
}
```

In this case, TResultType is:

```
public class SettingsResponse : BaseResponse
{
    public string LocationCode { get; set; }
    public string Ip { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationPrinterName { get; set; }
    public string MerchantNumber { get; set; }
    public string MessageControl { get; set; }
    public string PRIN { get; set; }
    public string SoftwareName { get; set; }
    public string SoftwareVersion { get; set; }
    public string SystemNumber { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I'm doing the request:

```
using (HttpClient client = GetHttpClient())
{
    var responseTask = client.GetAsync($"{url}/{paramsStr}");
    if (await Task.WhenAny(responseTask, Task.Delay(TimeoutSeconds * 1000)) == responseTask)
    {
        var response = await responseTask;
        return response.IsSuccessStatusCode
            ? await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Result<TResponse>>()
            : default(Result<TResponse>);
    }

    return Result<TResponse>.FromTimeout();
}
```

I'm always getting null in the property Data, even when the values are there in the json response.

Comment: Without code, I can simply offer "there is no spoon."

Comment: So what? All you are showing is a partial JSON with values masked. What is your question? What does your call look like, what do expect it to return etc?

Comment: a) Don't post images of code. b) Without an [mcve] this question is going to be closed and go unanswered.

Comment: We don't want your object, but how you are performing your request to receive your HttpResponse

Comment: [Images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Please copy and paste your code into your question. And show us how you're performing your request!!!!!

Comment: this is the code that is giving the return value: await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Result<TResponse>>()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result class with public setters in properties

```
public class Result<TResultType>
{
    public int? ErrorId { get; set; } // Todo: Use it!!!
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public ResponseErrorType ErrorType { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public TResultType Data { get; set; }
}
```

It is working now.